# select regular data and insert to average month values as update but error

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to select regular data from **reg_data3** and get average month values and insert into **average** table as update but it does not work well.

```
SELECT   
     year(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d'))as year, 
     month(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d')) as month, 
     round(avg(evep),2), 
     round(Avg(sunshine_hrs),2), 
     round(sum(rainfall),2), 
     round(AVG(max_temp),2), 
     round(avg(min_temp),2) 
FROM 
    reg_data3 
GROUP BY 
    year(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d')), 
    month(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d')) 
ORDER BY 1 Desc 

UPDATE 
    avg_month_val 
set 
    year='year' , 
    month='month',  
    evep='evep' , 
    sunshine_hrs='sun_shine_hrs', 
    rainfall='rainfall', 
    max_temp='max_temp', 
    min_temp='min_temp';
```

Comment: I tried to format that to see if I could read it. I failed. Can you format better please?

Comment: I tried too and decided to save it. Please see if that what you meant.

Comment: I redid it. Can you show what you get and what you actually want to get.

Comment: @Preet Sangha i want to update avg_month_val1 table using reg_data3 val.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE 
    avg_month_val 

set 
    `year`          =   YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')), 
    `month`         =   MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')), 
    `evep`          =   ROUND(AVG(`evep`), 2), 
    `sunshine_hrs`  =   ROUND(AVG(`sunshine_hrs`) ,2), 
    `rainfall`      =   ROUND(SUM(`rainfall`), 2), 
    `max_temp`      =   ROUND(AVG(`max_temp`), 2), 
    `min_temp`      =   ROUND(AVG(`min_temp`), 2) 

FROM 
    reg_data3 

GROUP BY 
    MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')), 
    MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: thanks to all.. sql syntax error what mean reg_data3 A what ever thanks